# Проверка условия при изменения размеров экрана window.onresize

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```
window.onresize = function(){

    let element = js.get('#visi-sm');


    if ( document.body.clientWidth < 980 ) {

        js.show(js.get('#yut'));
        js.get('#yut').replaceChild(element, js.get('.column-mobile'));
        js.hide(js.get('#yuti'));


    }else{

        js.show(js.get('#yuti'))
        console.log(js.get('#yut'))
        js.get('#visibility-sm').replaceChild(element, js.get('#yuti'));
        js.hide(js.get('#yut'));

    }

}
```

При изменения экрана происходит перенос блока, но происходит ошибка

> replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'

Как сделать так, чтобы код срабатывал только при переходи значения, указанного в условии, чтобы избежать ошибки?

Comment: Какую библиотеку используете?

Comment: это своя библиотека, просто берет див, но конфликт точно не в ней, вопрос состоит только чтобы срабатывал кода только при преодолении границы

Comment: Но ошибку вызывает именно ваша библиотечная функция. `js.get('.column-mobile')` возвращает только один элемент?

Comment: да точно, ошибка происходит из-за того, что скрывается элемент, он его не находит и вызывается ошибка, все работает корректно первый раз, элемент нужно обязательно скрыть для того, чтобы не было дублирования так как навешены евенты, из-за этого будет тормощить сайт

Comment: Вы уверены, что https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries не помогут вам в данной задаче?

Comment: конечно) потому что с помощью css нельзя переместиться по dom дереву

Comment: А что мешает сделать дубликат и в нужный момент показывать нужную копию?

Comment: 2 паралельных блока, в каждом из них будет около 10000 подгружаемых объектов, это очень сильно повлияет на производительность сайта

Comment: А изменением стиля нельзя добиться нужного вам эффекта? Можете подготовить минимальный пример (без 1000 подгружаемых объектов) ?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас проблема перемещения блока только при повторном ресайзе, то вы можете запоминать состояние перемещения блока, чтобы не пытаться переместить его каждый раз:

```js
var narrowScreen = 2; // что-либо, кроме 0 и 1, чтобы первый раз гарантированно отработал rsize
window.onresize = rsize;
rsize();

function rsize() {
  let element = js.get('#visi-sm');

  if (document.body.clientWidth < 980) {
    if (narrowScreen != 1) {
      js.show(js.get('#yut'));
      js.get('#yut').replaceChild(element, js.get('.column-mobile'));
      js.hide(js.get('#yuti'));
      narrowScreen = 1;
    }
  } else {
    if (narrowScreen != 0) {
      js.show(js.get('#yuti'))
      console.log(js.get('#yut'))
      js.get('#visibility-sm').replaceChild(element, js.get('#yuti'));
      js.hide(js.get('#yut'));
      narrowScreen = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Comment: 'replaceChild' on 'Node' все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: Какой именно `replaceChild` вызывает ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

рабочий вариант, js.get  Возвращает DOM-элемент, соответствующий переданному селектору, метод наподобий метода у jquery.

if ( document.body.clientWidth < 980 ) {

```
js.get('#blockMobile').appendChild(js.get('#blockForDrop'));
js.hide(js.get('#blockDesktop'));
```

}

window.onresize = function(){

```
let blockForDrop = js.get('#blockForDrop');

if ( document.body.clientWidth < 980 ) {


    let blockMobile = js.get('#blockMobile');
    js.show(blockMobile);
    blockMobile.appendChild(js.get('#blockForDrop'));
    js.hide(js.get('#blockDesktop'));
} else{

    let blockDesktop = js.get('#blockDesktop');
    js.show(blockDesktop);
    blockDesktop.appendChild(js.get('#blockForDrop'));
    js.hide(js.get('#blockMobile'));


}
```

}